# BizTalk 2016 wmi query failing

Tags: powershell, biztalk, wmi-query, windows-server-2016, biztalk-2016

In our Powershell deployment scripts we terminate inflight instances identified by the following query:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace Root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer -query "SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ServiceInstance WHERE (ServiceClass = 1 OR ServiceClass = 64) AND AssemblyName LIKE 'Our.AssemblyName'"
```

For some reason this has stopped working on a Windows 2016 server, failing with this message:

```
get-wmiobject : An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-wmiobject -namespace Root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer -query "SELECT * ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Some searching has pointed to recent OS [security patches](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d08c395-1550-4171-8c03-23e1d2a9afbc/microsoft-security-updates-cause-biztalk-admin-console-errors-an-internal-failure-occurred-for?forum=biztalkgeneral). We uninstalled the KB mentioned from all nodes.

The above query runs without failure on 2 nodes in one environment and 1 node in another. This one box still gives the above error. Not sure what caused the original problem but maybe the uninstall did not clean up properly.

Any ideas where to start looking to fix the problem? I was thinking maybe installing the patch again and uninstalling it to make sure it cleans up properly. It takes about 4 hours for the VM to boot after the uninstall so testing such theories take a long time.

Comment: 4 hours?   Can we help you with that first?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have auto patching that kept re-applying the patch. What added to the confusion was the patch number being different for each OS and then there is the 4 hour thing that made it really difficult to poke the issue.

On 2016 it is KB4345418 that is causing the problem.